# NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null - Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dictionary, dart, mobile

I want to read data from [this](https://en.gravatar.com/mwxgaf.json) JSON in this way (PLEASE READ CODE COMMENTS):

```dart
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  final id;

  Profile({Key? key, @required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  var data;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    void getData() async {
      Response response = await get(
          Uri.parse('https://en.gravatar.com/' + widget.id + '.json'));
      this.data = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
      // READ PLEASE >>> Data successfully is loaded from server & if you 
      // print this.data it will show full data in console <<< READ PLEASE
    }

    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Profile | MWX Gravatar Viewer',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Profile | MGV'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(this.data['entry'][0]['name']['familyName']), // Where raises error
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And i get this error while rendering page:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Profile(dirty, state: _ProfileState#35267):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("entry")
```

**NOTE:** After a hot reload error is gone & I CAN SEE THE DATA I NEEDED ON SCREEN but every time when I want to load the page  this error will be shown although I can see what I expected, after a hot reload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your body might be running and not waiting for your `getData()` on `initState`. Try to check if it's null before using it:

```
body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(this.data != null ? this.data['entry'][0]['name']['familyName'] : 'no data'), // Where raises error
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Or use a `FutureBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are calling network request and at same time you are using data which is null by default so you can use either `FutureBuilder()` or handle error by `null check`